# Android draw polyline maps V2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, polyline, supportmapfragment

I have a `List` with `LatLng` objects that form a route I want to draw on my map. I am using a `SupportMapFragment` and I call this method below on `onActivityCreated`. I have another method called from there that creates markers and that one is executed fine but my method below does not draw the polyline. I have searched for examples but could not find any that suit my needs. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

```
private void drawRoute() {
    List<LatLng> latLngs = CoordinateEntity.getRouteLatLngs();
    PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions();
    line.width(5);
    line.color(Color.RED);

    for (LatLng latLng : latLngs) {
        line.add(latLng);
    }

    getMap().addPolyline(line);
}
```

I have looked at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html) and other similar examples and all follow this code pattern

```
mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
  .add(new LatLng(lats, lons), new LatLng(late,lone))
  .width(5)
  .color(color));
```

Is this the only way a `Polyline` can be added to the map?

Comment: can you post  `line.add(latLng)` method?

Comment: line.add is a `PolyLineOptions` method.

Comment: The code looks fine actualy. Are you sure about the coordinates of the points? It could be drawn somewhere you are not looking.

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure about the coordinates. That's not the problem.

Comment: You can use this code to draw polyline on map. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36929578/5242161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my problem.

I had the play services jar added to my project and for some reason everything of the maps V2 api worked except drawing lines.

I then added the play services project as a dependency and after I did that everything worked.