# How to draw interactive Polyline on route google maps v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

i have the following **code which is drawing polylines for me and working fine,** But the problem is that its not drawing interactive polylines, drawn lines are missing some pixels !

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class testRoute extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap myMap;
    Polyline line;
    Context context;

    // Static LatLng
    LatLng startLatLng = new LatLng(30.707104, 76.690749);
    LatLng endLatLng = new LatLng(30.721419, 76.730017);

    public void onCreate(Bundle bd) {
        super.onCreate(bd);
        setContentView(R.layout.passanger_home_call);
        context = testRoute.this;

        // Temp GetTrails Button
        Button btntemp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pass_home_call_temp);
        btntemp.setOnClickListener(this);

        // GoogleMap myMap
        myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_pass_home_call)).getMap();
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(startLatLng));
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

        // Now auto clicking the button
        btntemp.performClick();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_pass_home_call_temp:
            String urlTopass = makeURL(startLatLng.latitude,
                    startLatLng.longitude, endLatLng.latitude,
                    endLatLng.longitude);
            new connectAsyncTask(urlTopass).execute();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        String url;

        connectAsyncTask(String urlPass) {
            url = urlPass;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.hide();
            if (result != null) {
                drawPath(result);
            }
        }
    }

    public String makeURL(double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat,
            double destlog) {
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        urlString.append("?origin=");// from
        urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelog));
        urlString.append("&destination=");// to
        urlString.append(Double.toString(destlat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
        return urlString.toString();
    }

    public class JSONParser {

        InputStream is = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {
        }

        public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                json = sb.toString();
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            return json;

        }
    }

    public void drawPath(String result) {
        if (line != null) {
            myMap.clear();
        }
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(endLatLng).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.redpin_marker)));
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(startLatLng).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.redpin_marker)));
        try {
            // Tranform the string into a json object
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                    .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);

            for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
                LatLng src = list.get(z);
                LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
                line = myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                                new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                        .width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

**Code is Working fine And Drawing Route from one place to another**  but not drawing the interactive Routes

Screent Shot :- [image]

I think problem is with my `drawPath()` method :

```
public void drawPath(String result) {
        if (line != null) {
            myMap.clear();
        }
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(endLatLng).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.redpin_marker)));
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(startLatLng).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.redpin_marker)));
        try {
            // Tranform the string into a json object
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                    .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);

            for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
                LatLng src = list.get(z);
                LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
                line = myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                                new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                        .width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

*Ignore The markers* just suggest me about adding interactive polyline?

Comment: What do you mean by saying interactive polylines / routes?

Comment: @MaciejGórski thanks for your reply ! i mean to blue line which is being drawn on map is not interactive, Blue line missing some pixels !  please have Look at screen Shot !

Comment: @Tarsem I am in the process of creating a boiler plate class for people to easily implement GDirection/polyline and I have borrowed some of your code. Please let me know if you wouldn't mind if I used it, I will of course credit you. If you need you can contact me on Twitter: beckahsheeler  Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/amalChandran/trail-android You could use the projections API to draw it as an overlay.

Comment: Thankyou the decodepoly method helped me solving my problem.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Instead of creating too many short `Polyline`s just create one like here:

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
    LatLng point = list.get(z);
    options.add(point);
}
line = myMap.addPolyline(options);
```

I'm also not sure you should use `geodesic` when your points are so close to each other.

Comment: is it possible to detect click on polyline?

Comment: i think for answers that could be `Yes` or `No`. Never a good idea create a new question.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Then my answer would be `Yes`.

Comment: This will only draw a path. if you want your path stick to road use google direction API.

Comment: @MaciejGórski Can you please help me in the issue in animating polyline if I am using com.google.maps.model.LatLng class rather than com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng class Here is the posted Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48473889/7948825.

Comment: you can shrink this code by just doing this new PolylineOptions()
                .addAll(list).width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);

Answer (score 27):

I've created a couple of map tutorials that will cover what you need

[Animating the map](http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part3) describes howto create polylines based on a set of LatLngs.
[Using Google APIs on your map : Directions and Places](http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part5) describes howto use the Directions API and animate a marker along the path.

Take a look at these 2 tutorials and the [Github project](https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/tree/master/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock) containing the sample app.

It contains some tips to make your code cleaner and more efficient:

- Using Google HTTP Library for more efficient API access and easy JSON handling.
- Using google-map-utils library for maps-related functions (like decoding the polylines)
- Animating markers

Answer (score 11):

You can use this method to draw polyline on googleMap

```
// Draw polyline on map
public void drawPolyLineOnMap(List<LatLng> list) {
    PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polyOptions.color(Color.RED);
    polyOptions.width(5);
    polyOptions.addAll(list);

    googleMap.clear();
    googleMap.addPolyline(polyOptions);

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (LatLng latLng : list) {
        builder.include(latLng);
    }

    final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    //BOUND_PADDING is an int to specify padding of bound.. try 100.
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, BOUND_PADDING);
    googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
}
```

You need to add this line in your gradle in case you haven't.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use `options.addAll(allPoints);` instead of `options.add(point);`

Answer (score 2):

Using the google maps projection api to draw the polylines on an overlay view enables us to do a lot of things. Check this [repo](https://github.com/amalChandran/trail-android) that has an example.

[image]