# navigation drawer and map activity on android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have created a navigation drawer `activity` and a map `activity` . Is it possible to make the map appears with a navigation drawer? . If you couldn't understand what i am saying , please search for **here maps** in the **Google Play**, they have the same idea that i want to create.

Comment: If you want to draw driver directions on map, probably there you will find solutions for your problems:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2
http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425499/how-to-draw-interactive-polyline-on-route-google-maps-v2-android
http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822

Answer (score 0):

use this tetorial to make the navigation drawer : [Navigation Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

then create a fragment for your map with this in the  xml :

```
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

(inside the relative Layout of course)

add a class for your fragment as

```
    public class YourFragmentName extends Fragment {
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Your_Parent_Activity = super.getActivity();
            //Initiate Context

Your_Fragment_Layout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_YourXmlLayout, container, false);

 map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  return Your_Fragment_Layout;
}
```

Comment: i added the fragment into the relative layout and  i made a class for my fragment but i got alot of errors , am just a beginner at android please help me ,

Comment: you can show me the errors or i can send you a sample code :)

Comment: make sure you've added this to your dependencies    
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'