# Draw a polyline in Android google maps as the user move

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

Hy, I'm a newbie in Android, and I've learned about android google maps. I'd like to tracking user movement and draw polyline path in android google maps in real time, can someone help me with the example? I can get the location chage interval but still don't know how to apply it into polyline and keep the data LatLng into array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw interactive Polyline on route google maps v2 android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425499/how-to-draw-interactive-polyline-on-route-google-maps-v2-android)

Comment: thanks for help, but i'd like to draw polyline path as the user move and show it on the device at real time.

Comment: explained the logic enjoy

Comment: if you have "start lat", "start lng", "end lat" and "end lng" then you can draw  like described in https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon

Comment: No-newbies like me are having the same question six years later :·)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this/related g.play services virsion line in your gradle in case you haven't.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
```

As [official doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) says , use this code.

```
GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add a thin red line from London to New York.
 Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
```

**Note**: Methods that modify a Polyline must be called on the main thread If not, an *IllegalStateException* will be thrown at run-time.

For a sake that i know you can find this code so here is my small logic

1. Keep start and end position `Latlng`  variables (`startLatlng` ,`endLatlng`)
2. As you can see in the example you cannot send hard coded values,pass your real values so take the location when user moves or may be after a certain time period
3. Write logic : `startLatlng` = new Latlng data that you got when user move / after a time period;
4. *only* for the first time `startLatlng` = `endLatlng` (use if condition with a *boolian* and change its value after it gets called )
5. call your method to draw Poly-line line with (`startLatlng` and `endLatlng`)
6. `endLatlng` = `startLatlng` (see only after you call that draw method set the start value to end value)

**Note**

If it's confusing use real values and try to understand what i explained. 
First time  both are same.
It darws a dot because both are in the same spot.(i guess) Now `startLatlng` & `endLatlng` both have the first same value.

Second time new location comes `startLatlng` changes.Then it cannot go to that *boolean* if method because it's only for the first time.

Now it call that method to draw line (*new* `startLatlng` and *old* endLatlng). Only after you call that draw method, your `endLatlng` gets that new `startLatlng` value.

But the next time when your full logic gets called with a very new data again that very new data assigns to `startLatlng`.

So in this way it can draw a line between the `startLatlng` (new Possition) to `endLatlng` (oldPossition).