# Android Google maps draw path while moving

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello I am using google map with `LocationListener`. I am able to draw path between points using *Fused API*

```
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 60 * 1);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000 * 60 * 1);
                                            }
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

and here I draw the path:

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                routePoints.add(latLng);
                Polyline route = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .width(5)
                        .color(Color.BLUE)
                        .geodesic(false)
                        .zIndex(3));
                route.setPoints(routePoints);

                                            }
```

The point is, I need to draw live path while user is moving and stop when user stop regardless of interval time of `LocationRequest`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this this method , so you can decide and change the values as you need. How much time interval and how much min distance is need to call this method. Works without internet too.

```
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private android.location.LocationListener myLocationListener;

    public void checkLocation() {

        String serviceString = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(serviceString);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }


        myLocationListener = new android.location.LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location locationListener) {

                if (isGPSEnabled(YourActivityName.this)) {
                    if (locationListener != null) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivityName.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivityName.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            return;
                        }

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (isInternetConnected(YourActivityName.this)) {
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }



            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }
        }; 

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, myLocationListener);  //  here the min time interval and min distance 
}
```

**isInternetConnected method**

```
public static boolean isInternetConnected(Context ctx) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connectivityMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        // Check if wifi or mobile network is available or not. If any of them is
        // available or connected then it will return true, otherwise false;
        if (wifi != null) {
            if (wifi.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (mobile != null) {
            if (mobile.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**isGpsEnabled method**

```
  public boolean isGPSEnabled(Context mContext) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
```

Logic: check `lastlocation` is the `currantLocation` by keeping variables and if yes it means you are not moved if no draw the path

Comment: thank you but I want a method without time interval I mean draw line while user is moving  not after interval , I cant make it very small interval due to battery issues. I want a procedure working only when user is moving.

Comment: @Radwa please note `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, myLocationListener);` this does not means it gets called after every second it means  , the difference needs to be at least a 1 second and 1 meter to call that method again.If  the location does not change again it never gets called more

Comment: I get your idea my problem is i made interval 1 minute it's draw the path but ignoring points I checked in less than minute I.e if  I check at A, then turn to B ,then C it draw from point A to point C ignoring point b as it take less than minute

Comment: @Radwa Its because the way you draw path is wrong.you are adding currant position and draw a line.It should be from last location to your currant location. so every time you call it it will draw a one from previous location to currant location

Comment: @Radwa check the logic that i have used -->http://stackoverflow.com/a/41294229/5188159

Comment: ok I am gonna check it but I draw the path from last location the problem is point B as I mentioned was within the minute and after minute user was at point C so it simply connect last loc A with new loc C ignoring B you get me

Comment: @Radwa yes if you call get location after a minute whatever the locations you pass through that minute wont be added. Correct. Thats why i suggest you to get the location based on the change of the position/distance instead of the time When ever you chage your possition get that location.Advantage is if you use a timer even you are in the same spot it gets called but this doesnt.   Otherwise you wont have a solution i guess

Comment: Thanks a lot I thought so too  is it good approach I mean for battery ?

Comment: @Radwa  it works fine i used it for main taxi app along with the method i provided so far results are good.

Comment: @Radwa call that method once after that `locationManager` listener will call it depending on the data you gave to it's params  eg: after 1 meter distance change

Comment: @Charu, can you plz provide working example with poly line draw. In my case it is drawing line though my mobile on same position. I followed your method.

Answer (score 0):

in you class define this method of google api :

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
     // make your code to draw path , and refresh the map to not hve a ot of path .

     }
```

for more details take see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249920/how-to-draw-path-as-i-move-starting-from-my-current-location-using-google-maps)

Comment: thanks but it's deprecated plus it need time interval too